# Using JQuery "Document.ready" in background page load?

Tags: jquery

I have a PDF component that goes and fetches a page to use as the content for the PDF. In that page Jquery does some showing and hiding of sections according to certain criteria.

I know this probably isn't possible but can I get the ready event to fire from the background page load?

Edit: the javascript is in the page that is being accessed as the source for the PDF and not the page creating the PDF.

Edit: It doesn't matter, I have done it server side.

Comment: I don't think jQuery can see when the PDF component has finished loading the PDF. The component itself should be able to fire a javascript event then I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, because you don't actually EMBED pdf's in your page, like you do with swf files.

In fact, the way how browser handle this kind of files (pdf, mov, mp3, etc), it's up for users settings. For example, i set up my browser to download & open pdf files in fox it reader rather than open into browser ;)

Anyhow, i think you can embed pdf into a flash movie which can execute a js function when is loaded. Just an idea :)